# Editing 2007 MS Access *.accdb using OLE DB connection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ms-access, connection, accdb, ole-db

Can you edit a 2007 MS Access .accdb file format using the OLE DB connection?

I have made the connection using the following:

[Connecting to a 2007 Microsoft Access database (.accdb) in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000024000000)

I can add and view the tables from this file in ArcMap, but when I try to start an edit session on this table, it errors out with the follwoing 2 errors:

- No editable layers
- Check to see that you have the appropriate permissions

I created a .accdb file from scratch, so it is not read only.

Under the Advanced tab in the Data Link Properties for the OLE DB connection, I have set the ReadWrite option check mark and unchecked the rest and I am still unable to edit this table in ArcMap.

[image]

Click image for larger version Name: OLE_DB_Advanced.jpg Views: 14 Size: 44.7 KB ID: 25411

There isn't much documentation on the OLE DB connection in the help file other than how to connect as posted above. Can anyone point out what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **ArcGIS 10.1 Help** indicates that you cannot edit the attributes of Excel or MS Access files, added through an Ole DB connection, because they have no ObjectID field. You can **Copy** the data to a **fGDB table** and then edit it. Or you can script Python to edit the native MS formats.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, but thanks. That explains my issue.